# XSLT with multiple namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am quite new to stylesheets, so I am having some elementary problems.

Here is my XML:

```
<NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://blahblahblah">


<NS1:Body>
      <NS2:STR xmlns:NS2="http://blahblah">
         <NS2:STD>
            <NS2:ST>CA</NS2:ST>
            <NS2:CTY>Los Angeles</NS2:CTY>
            <NS2:CY>Artesia</NS2:CY>
            <NS2:STGC>05</NS2:STGC>
            <NS2:CTYGC>037</NS2:CTYGC>
            <NS2:CYGC>0160</NS2:CYGC>
            <NS2:GC>050370160</NS2:GC>
            <NS2:STTR>0.065000</NS2:STTR>
            <NS2:CTYTR>0.025000</NS2:CTYTR>
            <NS2:CYTR>0.000000</NS2:CYTR>
            <NS2:TotalTR>0.090000</NS2:TotalTR>
            <NS2:EffectiveDate>2014-09-24</NS2:EffectiveDate>
         </NS2:STD>
         <NS2:STD>
            <NS2:ST>CA</NS2:ST>
            <NS2:CTY>Los Angeles</NS2:CTY>
            <NS2:CY>Cerritos</NS2:CY>
            <NS2:STGC>05</NS2:STGC>
            <NS2:CTYGC>037</NS2:CTYGC>
            <NS2:CYGC>6430</NS2:CYGC>
            <NS2:GC>050370160</NS2:GC>
            <NS2:STTR>0.065000</NS2:STTR>
            <NS2:CTYTR>0.025000</NS2:CTYTR>
            <NS2:CYTR>0.000000</NS2:CYTR>
            <NS2:TotalTR>0.090000</NS2:TotalTR>
            <NS2:EffectiveDate>2014-09-24</NS2:EffectiveDate>
         </NS2:STD>
      </NS2:STR>
   </NS1:Body>
</NS1:Envelope>
```

And here is my stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:NS1="http://blahblahblah"
xmlns:NS2="http://blahblah">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/NS1:Envelope/NS1:Body/NS2:STR/NS2:STD">
  <xsl:element name="CALL_ENGINE_RESPONSE">
    <xsl:value-of select="NS2:ST" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The response I get is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



         <CALL_ENGINE_RESPONSE>CA</CALL_ENGINE_RESPONSE>
         <CALL_ENGINE_RESPONSE>CA</CALL_ENGINE_RESPONSE>
```

I am trying to get a response like

```
         <CALL_ENGINE_RESPONSE>
         <STATE>CA</STATE>
         <STATE>CA</STATE>
         </CALL_ENGINE_RESPONSE>
```

Please let me know if I should edit my formatting, and I apologize for making it so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handling of namespaces is perfectly fine!

To solve your problem, what you could do is have a template that matches a common ancestor of your `NS2:STD` and output the `CALL_ENGINE_RESPONSE` there, before selecting the `NS2:STD` element

```
<xsl:template match="NS2:STR">
   <CALL_ENGINE_RESPONSE>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="NS2:STD" />
   </CALL_ENGINE_RESPONSE>
</xsl:template>
```

In the template that matches `NS2:STD` you would then output the `STATE` element

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:NS1="http://blahblahblah" xmlns:NS2="http://blahblah" exclude-result-prefixes="NS1 NS2">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="NS2:STR">
      <CALL_ENGINE_RESPONSE>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="NS2:STD"/>
      </CALL_ENGINE_RESPONSE>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="NS2:STD">
      <STATE>
         <xsl:value-of select="NS2:ST"/>
      </STATE>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note there is no need to put the full path to the `NS2:STD` element in the template match. You would only need to do this if there were other `NS2:STD` elements at different positions in the hierarchy that you didn't want to match.

Comment: Thanks Tim, could you please explain to me what the exclude-result-prefixes does?

Comment: It means the serialiser won't output these namespace declarations if they are not used in the output XML. Try removing the line from the XSLT, and see what happens!